# loop inside mat table angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to make a loop to display some data in my angular material table, but I can't do it because I don't know how.

```
 // <img src=" assets/{{element[col.key][0].position}}.jpg alt="img"> // this way works out of the loop.
```

**ts.file**

```
  columns = [
    {key: 'position', display ...., config : {isPosition:true}},

  ];
```

**material.table.Components**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">

 <ng-container *ngIf="col.config.isPosition">
          <div *ngFor="let element of col.config.isPosition">
             <img src=" assets/{{element[col.key].position}}.jpg alt="img">
         </div> 
 </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

Comment: what is your angular material version?

Comment: my angular material version is 12

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `*ngFor` for angular material table. You have to follow the implementation rules.
You have to define your data in **.ts** file as below and then you can bind it to tr like `*matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"`.

Here is an example from angular material official site that is available in [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

result:
[image]

For implementing `img` tag you can create an object that contains src of the images and map it to columns yourself then use that object in DOM.

Comment: I know how to do this, I'm looking for another way to do it so your answer does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

A little too late on the thread but, I was able to solve this similar problem on my app. Contrary to the first answer, we can use the *ngFor on the ng table.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="materials">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns;" [matColumnDef]="col">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ col | uppercase }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let material"> {{ material[col] }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>
</table>
```

the `material[col]` part of code is the key part of this problem. Basically if we try to access the `material`, it is the individual json of the array. That json contains every property, which is we expects to be defined in our `columns`. To access each properties of our json, we just need to call the `json[propertyNameInString]`, which in our case is the `material[col]`.